# Unable to do an SVN dump -- Error E720002 and format errors

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm new to SVN, so forgive the possible straightforward problem.  I'm trying to do an Subversion dump of one of my projects:

```
svnadmin dump C:\code\project1 -r 9 > repo.dmp
```

Unfortunately I'm getting this error:

```
svnadmin: E720002: Can't open file 'project1\format': The system cannot 
find the file specified.
```

It appears to be looking for the `format` file which is actually located at `project1\.svn\format`. This has me puzzled as I'd expect it to look in the `.svn` subdirectory of project1, but instead is looking in the root.

I then tried:

```
svnadmin dump project1\.svn -r 9 > repo.dmp
```

But this resulted in:

```
svnadmin: E165005: Expected repository format '3' or '5'; found format '12'
```

I thought this was an issue with my format being out of data since that is a common issue from what I've read.  My server is repositoryhosting.com and they are on 1.7.1 server.  On my client, I am using TortoiseSVN with SVN:

TortoiseSVN 1.7.4, Build 22459 - 64 Bit
Subversion 1.7.2

Upon further reading, I might be confusing things and needing to go against the actual repository instead of my local working copy. Problem is that the repository is in the cloud hosted by repositoryhosting.com and svnadmin won't accept URLs as repo locations, only local paths.

would love some help with what's going on...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**svnadmin dump** is for working on the repository(server side), not the working copy (client side)
The errormessage about format is misleading as it searches for the format file in repository and finds a file with same name in your workingcopy.

If you are interested to get a full backup of your repository you can use **svnrdump** for this purpose. It is used the same way than svnadmin dump, however it is possible to get the dump from an **remote** repository:
use

```
svnrdump  dump -r0:HEAD [URL_TO_YOUR_REPO] > Your_dumpfile.dmp
```

**THIS IS A NEW SVN 1.7 FEATURE**

Comment: Should the command be: `svnrdump dump -r0:HEAD [URL_TO_YOUR_REPO] > Your_dumpfile.dmp` ? (note exta _dump_ argument)

Comment: @David: You are right! Thanks for pointing it out! I just fiexd it now

Comment: So how can you remotely "load" this dump file onto another repository.

Comment: svnrdump load <URL> ; and optional username password and all the other parameters you may need to commit

Comment: How to load the dump file in offline mode ?