# How can I download my google code repository to be used with TortoiseSVN Repo Browser

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, google-code

I'm trying to download the code repository from a google project I 
created a while ago. When I download it I'm getting a folder called source-archive with a .svn folder in every directory. Does this include all of the history (commits) I have made. Also, I have tried connecting to this repository using Tortoise SVN using the repo browser, but it doesn't seem to recognize it 
as a repository. I don't know exactly what format this is in that I have 
downloaded.

[image: source download link]
[image: source downloaded from google code]
[image: repo browser doesn't recognize it as a repository]

To download the code repository: I go to archived., then source, then 
source again and finally "Download the code for this repo."

https://code.google.com/p/config-repo/

Any ideas how I can get a copy of my code (not just the most recent copy, 
I want all of my commits and history).

Thanks to alroc for the solution. The commands I used to download the full repository just in case someone wants to do the same:

```
svnrdump  dump -r0:HEAD http://config-repo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk > config-repo.dmp
svnadmin create svn-config-repo2
svnadmin load svn-config-repo2 < C:\Users\slark\config-repo.dmp
```

Comment: Did you see the instructions on the [Source](https://code.google.com/p/config-repo/source/checkout) tab? Essentially you need to *checkout* from the server to get a *working copy*. If you *download*, you get a static single version of the code. [TortoiseSVN Checkout](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with TortoiseSVN (well, you *could*, but you'd have to `export` each revision individually to get your desired results, and I really don't think you want to have 285 copies of the project lying around to sift through).

What you probably want to do is to dump the whole repository, then load it into a local repository so that you can work on it from there. You can use [`svnrdump`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8867031/1324345) to produce the dumpfile containing the entire remote repository.

You'll then need to create a new repository locally with [`svnadmin create`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.create.html), and [`svnadmin load`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html) to load the contents of that dumpfile into that repository.

See also [Repository data migration using svnadmin](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate)

Then use TortoiseSVN to connect to that local repository you just created and loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know of svnrdump.. the r is the trick because I was trying svndump and it was complaining about it not being local.