# How are revision numbers managed when two SVN repositories are merged?

Tags: svn, merge, repository, svnadmin, revision-history

This question: [SVN: Moving repository trunk to another's branch (with history)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646003/svn-moving-repository-trunk-to-anothers-branch-with-history) outlines a history-preserving process for merging in one repository as a sub-directory of another. I need to do a similar merge, but I'm trying to understand how the revision numbers will be managed in the new combined repository.

Assuming both "RepositoryA" and "RepositoryB" each already have a "revision 5", if revision 5 of "RepositoryA/trunk" is relocated to "RepositoryB/RepAProject/trunk", what will it be numbered? Will the revision numbers for both repositories be updated? Or will the merged-in repository get new sequential revision numbers appropriate for the date of merge?

And and as a bonus question, will it still be possible for users to `svn switch --relocate` from the old repo to the new subdirectory, or will the new repository UUID prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The merged-in repository will get new sequential revision numbers appropriate for the inserts of the new inport commits (6 - 10 in your example), but their timestamps will be consistent with what you saw in the original repository.

The `svnadmin load` will import each of the five revisions in order.

After importing the old repos (with 5 revisions) the destination repos will have 10 revisions, but revisions 6-10 will have earlier timestamps than revisions 1-5.

Be aware that in live systems other commits area allowed mid-import process.

As you correctly answered, the change in the UUID will prevent the `svn switch --relocate` command from working.